# How to restrict access for a back-end just to the internal network

Tags: backend, haproxy, restrict

I have an HAProxy with more than twenty backends and I need to limit access to one specific backend, CP-API.MACKMIL.COM, to the following internal network subnets:

```
10.10.0.0/16
10.20.0.0/16
10.30.0.0/16
10.40.0.0/16
```

Currently, with the following query, this domain, CP-API.MACKMIL.COM, can be accessed from the outside world but I want to limit that.

```
curl -vvv -H'Host: cp-api.mackmil.com' https://api.mackmil.com/initializations
```

My Haproxy config is as follows,

```
frontend http-https
bind :80 accept-proxy
bind :443 accept-proxy ssl crt /etc/pki/tls/private/wildcard.mackmil.com.pem crt /etc/pki/tls/private/wildcard.mackmil.de.pem

acl host_cp  hdr(host) -i cp-api.mackmil.com
acl host_cp  hdr(host) -i cp-api.prod.mackmil.com


use_backend app_cp   if host_cp

backend app_cp
server swarm-worker_10.10.30.199 10.10.30.199:64042 check
server swarm-worker_10.10.40.114 10.10.40.114:64042 check
server swarm-worker_10.20.40.159 10.20.40.159:64042 check
server swarm-worker_10.20.30.190 10.20.30.190:64042 check
server swarm-worker_10.30.40.143 10.30.40.143:64042 check
server swarm-worker_10.30.40.161 10.30.40.161:64042 check
server swarm-worker_10.40.40.107 10.40.40.107:64042 check
server swarm-worker_10.40.40.107 10.40.40.107:64042 check
```

I am struggling on applying this restriction in HTTP/HTTPS mode for just this endpoint. 
How can I apply this restriction for this backend?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It got fixed by putting this in that backend:

```
acl internal_subnets src 10.10.0.0/16
acl internal_subnets src 10.20.0.0/16
acl internal_subnets src 10.30.0.0/16
acl internal_subnets src 10.40.0.0/16
http-request deny if ! internal_subnets
```